# How do I delete a row with a pattern in R?

Tags: r, filter, grepl

I have a dataframe where I want to delete all rows with specific pattern. I am confused with compiling a regular expression.

Data:

```
structure(list(id = 1:5, email = c("1@gmail.com", "2@gmail.com", 
"3@gmail.com", "4@pattern.com", "5@pattern.com")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
data <- data %>%
  filter(email != ".+@pattern.com")
```

But something is wrong with my regex. What is the most effective way to compose a regular expression for such patterns? What is the proper regex pattern for my sample case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses `grepl` to perform a regex comparison

```
libary(dplyr)

data %>%
  filter(!grepl("@pattern.com$", email))

  id       email
1  1 1@gmail.com
2  2 2@gmail.com
3  3 3@gmail.com
```

Comment: nice, thank you! do you know how to compose the general regular expression for such cases?

Comment: @k1rgas Can you provide additional information for what you're looking for?  Are you looking for multiple patterns?

Comment: I mean a solution without ```grepl``` but with regex

Comment: @k1rgas Spend some time reading `?grepl` as the first parameter is regex.  This works by passing a regex pattern to `grepl` which creates a logical vector that is used by `filter` to return desired results.  The above example uses `$` which is regex for end of line.

Answer (score 1):

In `base R` you can remove the rows in `which` the pattern `@pattern.com` is detected by the function `grepl`in the `email` column:

```
data[-which(grepl("@pattern.com", data$email)),]
  id       email
1  1 1@gmail.com
2  2 2@gmail.com
3  3 3@gmail.com
```

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(id = 1:5, email = c("1@gmail.com", "2@gmail.com", 
                                           "3@gmail.com", "4@pattern.com", "5@pattern.com")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
```

Comment: Can also use `data[!grepl("@pattern.com$", data$email), ]` to negate the pattern